# How to add the comment options and the beneficiary

Tags: javascript, blockchain, steemit

I would like to add the comment options and the beneficiary using this simple javascript function in my own dapp.
I can broadcast the article to the steem blockchain already but I don't know how to add the beneficiary for the article.

I took the code from an old tutorial and it is the simplest and working easy one I found so far, but I can't figure out how to add the beneficiary, and I'm sure that is just an extra line of code.

```
<head>
    <title>steem-js posting example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
function postArticle()
{
  steem.broadcast.comment(
    document.getElementById('postingKey').value, // posting wif
    '', // author, leave blank for new post
    'dapptest', // first tag
    document.getElementById('username').value, // username
    'name-of-my-test-article-post', // permlink
    document.getElementById('title').value, // Title
    document.getElementById('article').value, // Body of post
    // json metadata (additional tags, app name, etc)
    { tags: ['secondtag'], app: 'dapp-test!' },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        alert('Failure! ' + err);
      else
        alert('Success!');
    }
  );
}
```